# in R, selecting rows from mydataframe based upon array of values when array and mydataframe are unequal length

Tags: arrays, r, rows, subset, intersect

I have the following data called gg and yy.

```
> str(gg)
 num [1:1992] 128 130 132 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 ...
> str(yy)
'data.frame':   2103 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ grp  : num  128 130 132 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 ...
 $ predd: num  -0.963 -1.518 1.712 -11.286 -8.195 ...
>
```

You'll notice that the first several values of gg match the first several from yy.

I would like to select rows from yy if the value yy$grp matches any value in gg.  The issue is that gg and yy are of unequal length.  Further, there are some values of gg that are not present in yy$grp and also some values of yy$grp not present in gg.

I can't seem to get this to work.  It is basically an intersection of the two data sets based upon the index value I mentioned (gg, or yy$grp).

I've tried:

```
inters<-intersect(gg,yy$grp)
yyint<-yy[yy$grp==inters,]
```

but get the following

```
Warning message:
In yy$grp == inters :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

> str(yya)
'data.frame':   28 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ grp  : num  128 130 132 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 ...
 $ predd: num  -0.963 -1.518 1.712 -11.286 -8.195 ...
```

yya should be much longer, according to my plans at least.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming the use of a single `=` is a typo. Regardless, you probably just want `%in%` here.

Comment: Yes, it should be a ==.  I edited it to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, I think this is what you want:

```
yy[yy$grp %in% gg,]
```